# For a proper scheme $X,$ $X(\mathbb{Z})=X(\mathbb{Q})?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral model of a $\mathbb{Q}$-variety. If $X$ is proper, I found in a paper (page 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.11763.pdf) that says $X(\mathbb{Z})=X(\mathbb{Q})$ from the valuation criterion of properness.

But from the criterion, all I can do is that the existence of a $\mathbb{Q}$-point in $X$ implies the existence of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-points for every prime number $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ by a prime ideal $(p)$.

My question is

(1) Does the existence of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-points for every prime number $p$ imply the existence of a $\mathbb{Z}$-point for such scheme $X$?

(2) Does the statement remain true when $X$ is a general proper scheme?

Any references of this fact or similar statement are welcome. I did not find one; maybe it is too easy to mention.

Comment: I don't know a perfect reference, but it's just this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BX7

You can extend your map uniquely from $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ to some open $U\subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$-- just keep track of the primes which show up in any presentation of your map and remove those that appear in the denominator. Then, use the above iteratively to extend over the missing primes $\{p_i\}=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})-U$. This works for any Dedekind scheme.

Comment: @Alex Youcis Thank you! This is very helpful.